# Oracle Trigger not working

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to develop a trigger which triggers when the value for a field is not 'Y' or 'N'. My code is below which is not working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ONLY_Y_N
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF flag
ON checktable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :new.flag <>'Y' OR  :new.flag <>'N' THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'Please insert Y  or N ');
END IF;
END ONLY_Y_N;
```

Please help

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate method for this would be a check constraint, not a trigger.

Maybe a NOT NULL constraint as well

Answer (score 4):

As David Aldridge says, you want a check constraint not a trigger.  However, the reason your trigger doesn't work is this condition:

```
IF :new.flag <>'Y' OR  :new.flag <>'N' THEN
```

Since 'Y' <> 'N' and 'N' <> 'Y' this will never be true!  You need:

```
IF :new.flag <>'Y' AND  :new.flag <>'N' THEN
```

or more succinctly:

```
IF :new.flag not in ('Y', 'N') THEN
```

So the check constraint solution would be:

```
alter table checktable add constraint only_y_n check (flag in ('Y', 'N'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you should have `AND` instead of `OR`. Your current code will raise an exception no matter the value of `FLAG`. Better yet, use `NOT IN` instead:

```
IF :new.flag NOT IN ('Y', 'N') THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'Please insert Y  or N ');
END IF;
```